# Extend abstract class which implement another class

Tags: java, class, interface, abstract

I am very new to OOP and going through a project code related to parser.
This contains following classes and interface.

```
    public interface Parser {
    }

    public abstract class AbstractParser implements Parser{
    }

    public class CSVParser extends AbstractParser{
    }

    public class XMLParser extends AbstractParser{
    }
```

I am not able to understand why it is done?

Comment: Interface only defines the signatures, abstract classes can implement _some_ of the methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a basic OOP design, Its basically an example of `"Program for Interface rather than implementation"`, To be more clear read once about SOLID design principles.

Now here in this code, There is an `Parser` interface, so If any class is a Parser then it must implement it, So again, If we want to give some default behavior to every parser, that's why there is AbstractParser.

To understand this code, you must see once JDK source code of Collections.
Here You will see, `List, Set, Map` are interfaces, then you have `AbstrictList, AbstractSet, AbstractMap` classes which are defined as abstract and have default implementations for some methods like `size()`. Then you have concrete implementation like `ArrayList, HashMap, HashSet` which you can instantiate. 
I will suggest you once go through the Collections framework design, and [SOLID principles](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The interface `Parser` represents the contract that *ALL* parsers must provide.

`AbstractParser` implements *only part* of that contract, the parts that are the same for all parsers (if there are any common parts) and may also provide some protected methods that can be useful to implementing concrete classes.

`CSVParser` and `XMLParser` are concrete implementations. They fulfill the contract of `Parser` using the common facilities provided by `AbstractParser`.

This pattern is a way of factoring out common code so it is written only once and shared by all implementations.  The concrete classes need to implement only the code that is unique to their specific requirements.

Comment: Thank you!What is the name of this kind of pattern?

Comment: I'm sure it has a name but I've been using it since before OOP existed (the 1970's).  I'm sure somebody will chime in with the "official" name.  I just call it "factoring out common code".

Comment: Its basically, "Program for interface rather than implementation", please see my answer hope it may help you to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

The interface Parser can be used to declare methods like parse with its return types and input parameters.

The implementing class like CSVParser and XMLParser will define the body of the methods using method overriding a typical Object Oriented behaviour.

The abstract class is introduced in between to introduce any state if needed for the Parser eg: FileHandle,LogHandle.